# Remote Debugging MobileFirst app on Windows Tablet

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ibm-mobilefirst, win-universal-app

I have a MobileFirst Hybrid Windows Tablet app bug that's only reproducible on a few device types so I'd like to use the "Run on Remote Machine" feature of Visual Studio 2013 to debug.  I've been able to do this with the 6.3 version of MobileFirst Studio, but in my current version MobileFirst 7.1 Studio, I can't seem to get my built apps to point anywhere but my local development MobileFirst server (which doesn't work on the remote machine).

Basically in previous versions, when the app was built, I'd see these lines inside the index.html file within the Windows Tablet app.

```
WL.StaticAppProps = {
   "APP_DISPLAY_NAME": "WorkExecution",
   "APP_ID": "WorkExecution",
   "APP_SERVICES_URL": "http:\/\/maxanywin8:10080\/MaximoAnywhere\/apps\/services\/",
   "APP_VERSION": "7.5.2.1",
   "ENVIRONMENT": "windows8",
   "LOGIN_DISPLAY_TYPE": "embedded",
   "WORKLIGHT_PLATFORM_VERSION": "6.3.0.0",
   "WORKLIGHT_ROOT_URL": "http:\/\/maxanywin8:10080\/MaximoAnywhere\/apps\/services\/api\/WorkExecution\/windows8\/"
};
```

Notice that my hostname and port was embedded into the worklight_root_url and app_services_url.  I could easily change them to point to our production MobileFirst Server so I could debug on the remote machin. However in the new version of MobileFirst studio 7.1, the index.html looks like this:

```
 WL.StaticAppProps = {
   "APP_DISPLAY_NAME": "Work Execution",
   "APP_ID": "WorkExecution",
   "APP_SERVICES_URL": "\/apps\/services\/",
   "APP_VERSION": "7.6.1",
   "APP_VERSION_WPUNI": "7.6.1",
   "ENVIRONMENT": "windows8",
   "ENVIRONMENT_WPUNI": "windowsphoneuniversal",
   "LOGIN_DISPLAY_TYPE": "embedded",
   "WORKLIGHT_PLATFORM_VERSION": "7.1.0.0",
   "WORKLIGHT_ROOT_URL": "\/apps\/services\/api\/WorkExecution\/windows8\/",
   "WORKLIGHT_ROOT_URL_WPUNI": "\/apps\/services\/api\/WorkExecution\/windowsphoneuniversal\/"
};
```

Notice that the server and port information has been removed.  However, the app still tries to only connect to my maxanywin8:10080 development server when deployed to the remote machine.

Where is the server host and port information kept in this new version?  I've searched my windows/native directory and can't find any reference to it.

Comment: I've also tried the programmatic approach, and WL.App.setServerURL fails with this error:  "WL.App.setServerUrl(..) is only available on iOS, Android and WP environments."

Answer (score 0):

I found where the server location is stored now for Windows apps, it's moved to the windows8/native/AppName.Shared/wlclient.properties file now.